# Duplicate id founds while select query is fire

Tags: soql, soap-api, soap

I am doing coding in Eclipse.
I am using SOAP API for that.

there is method called query()

i am use following code

```
PartnerConnection connection = ForceConnection.getOrgConnection();
List<SObject> objects = new ArrayList<SObject>();
QueryResult queryResults = connection.query("select name from book__c");
for (int i=0;i<queryResults.getRecords().length;i++) {
                SObject so = (SObject)queryResults.getRecords()[i];
                objects.add(so);
            }
```

while update

```
SObject[] sObjArray = new SObject[objects.size()];
objects.toArray(sObjArray);
SaveResult[] upsertResults = connection.update(sObjArray);
```

getting Error

> Id not specified in an update call' status Code='MISSING_ARGUMENT

while I am change the query with

```
select id,name from book__c
```

getting Error

> Duplicate ID found

Please any one has Idea..Guide me...

Comment: Issue should be in your 
"SObject[] sObjArray = new SObject[objects.size()];
objects.toArray(sObjArray);
SaveResult[] upsertResults = connection.update(sObjArray);" 

Change SObject[] to List<Sobject> and use sObjArray.addall(Objects)

Comment: Issue is not in update Syntax...

Issue is while select Query is fire without ID parameter id=null 
and while select Query with ID parameter ID is come 2 times...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no solution for that in SOAP API used with Partner WSDL. This is an idea in a salesforce site.

Please refer to the following links:

- [Salesforce site link](https://success.salesforce.com/apex/ideaView?id=08730000000hPM1AAM)
- [Salesforce site link 2](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000171402&language=en_US)

#### I also have a solution, but it is not logic (use if required)

```
PartnerConnection connection = ForceConnection.getOrgConnection();
List<SObject> objects = new ArrayList<SObject>();
QueryResult queryResults = connection.query("select Id,name from book__c");

for (int i=0;i<queryResults.getRecords().length;i++) {
    SObject so = (SObject)queryResults.getRecords()[i];
    so.removeField("Id");
    objects.add(so);
}
```

---

#### Note

1. There are 2 times Id was come in the Sobject.
2. It means there are 2 fields as name Id
3. so remove 1 field of id from the object
4. using the the following line

   ```
   so.removeField("Id");
   ```